# Gnuplot: loading palette?

Tags: gnuplot, color-palette

I'm certainly missing something very obvious but how to change the basic colors Gnuplot uses (which can be seen via command `test`)?

I want to define some colors and then to be able to use them as basic colors with `linecolor 1`, etc.

Here's an example, which to my understanding should override colors -- and yet it doesn't:

```
set palette defined (0 '#A6CEE3',\
                     1 '#1F78B4',\
                     2 '#B2DF8A',\
                     3 '#33A02C',\
                     4 '#FB9A99',\
                     5 '#E31A1C',\
                     6 '#FDBF6F',\
                     7 '#FF7F00' )
set style arrow 1 \
    nohead \
    linecolor 1 \
    linewidth 2
set style arrow 2 \
    nohead \
    linecolor 2 \
    linewidth 4
set style line 3 \
    linetype 1 \
    linewidth 3 \
    linecolor 3
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-2:10]
set arrow from 1,-2 to 1,10 arrowstyle 1
set arrow from -10,3 to 10,3 arrowstyle 1
plot sin(x) with lines linestyle 3, \
    5 with vectors arrowstyle 2
```

The colors are taken from the [paired](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes/blob/master/paired.pal) [palette](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes), while on the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLmg.png) Gnuplot still uses the default colors (can be seen on the background, which is part of the `test` command output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems palettes are used to convert a continuous analogue value into a smooth colour choice. You only want to "index" into the palette at the defined points you specified, using discrete values of 0, 1 ... 7 to get to the colour. 
It looks like you can do this if you use a *colourspec* of the form `linecolor palette cb`*index*.  You need to set the range of the "colourbar" first. Try

```
set cbrange [0:7]
set style arrow 1 \
    nohead \
    linecolor palette cb 1 \
    linewidth 2
set style arrow 2 \
    nohead \
    linecolor palette cb 2 \
    linewidth 4
set style line 3 \
    linetype 1 \
    linewidth 3 \
    linecolor palette cb 3
```

Add `unset colorbox` to not show the range of colours at the right-hand side.

Comment: Yeah, I know about `rgbcolor` but that was exactly the point: instead of declaring HEX in every style I was thinking of simplifying the routine and simply overriding 0-7 colors. I mean, it's a way more flexible and once defined, you don't need to think in all those `#......` :) But thanks anyway.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative using indexes.

Comment: Now, this does work, thanks! :) (Just for the record, one can also use variables, of course: instead of setting a palette, just define some vars, `my_fancy_color = '#A6CEE3'`, and then use them with `rgb` property like this: `linecolor rgb my_fancy_color1`)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the original question, but I thought it was a request for information on how to change the set of colors used by basic line types 1 through N, as shown by the "test" command. The commands needed are:

```
set linetype 1 lc '#A6CEE3'
set linetype 2 lc '#1F78B4'
set linetype 3 lc '#B2DF8A'
set linetype 4 lc '#33A02C'
set linetype 5 lc '#FB9A99'
set linetype 6 lc '#E31A1C'
set linetype 7 lc '#FDBF6F'
set linetype 8 lc '#FF7F00'
set linetype cycle 8
```

This becomes a a new sequence of colors used in generating successive plot elements and shown by the "test" command.  The final line tells it to restart the same sequence of colors at linetype 9 (and 17, 25, ...).

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely right, and I was just stupid, sorry :).